# Connect to socket in infinate loop with python

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop

I have a ssh deamon running on my local machine. I want infinitely connect to ssh deamon and echo received data.
Here is my script.

```
[azatuni@noc python-tests]$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
PORT = 22
DESTIP = '127.0.0.1'

while 1 == 1:
 s.connect((DESTIP, PORT))
 data = s.recv(1024)
 s.close()
 print data
```

But when I run script, recieves the following error. But wihout loop, everything works fine.

```
[azatuni@noc python-tests]$ ./test.py
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((DESTIP, PORT))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 167, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Your posted code is not correct, please paste exactly the code you are using.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to create a new socket before connecting again. This will work for your:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import socket  
PORT = 22  
DESTIP = '127.0.0.1'  
while 1 == 1:  
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
 s.connect((DESTIP, PORT))  
 data = s.recv(1024) 
 s.close()  

 print data
```

Be aware that code you've posted has errors in it:

```
data = s.recv(102SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

Comment: It was a wrong copy paste, sorry. I edited question.

Comment: Sorry, but you wrote same as code in my scrpit which doesn't works.

Comment: No. You are creating the socket outside of the while loop. My code does it inside the loop.